# Print text value from xml using sed

Tags: sed

using a one line sed command , how could i get the **something** and **someone** value?

```
<value name="something">someone</value>
```

Using the following regex `<value name="(.*)">(.*)<\/value>` i could retrieve the values with success using the site https://www.regex101.com/. But i'm not sure how could i do it using the command line.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: sure, i'll update the question =)

Comment: you should specify a bit the possible content of something and someone (for special char `<>/"`) that can create perturbation in delimiter pattern or we can assume this is only word with eventually space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
sed 's#.*name="\(.*\)">\(.*\)<.*#\1 \2#g'
```

**Test**

```
$ echo "<value name=\"something\">someone</value>" | sed 's#.*name="\(.*\)">\(.*\)<.*#\1 \2#g'
something someone
```

Comment: @Thales Glad to hear it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

`sed -r 's/.*"(.*)">(.*)<.*>$/\1 \2/'`

Comment: you can use `sed -r 's/.*"(.*)">(.*)<.*$/\1 \2/' file` instead

Answer (score 0):

Noting the [usual caveats](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/7552) about parsing XML with regular expressions, here's an XML parsing tool in action on your sample data that finds the attribute value and tag value for a "value" tag with a "name" attribute.

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//value[@name]/@name' -n -v '//value[@name]' -n file.xml
```

```
something
someone
```